# Как получить доступ к верхнему UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

Имеется:

```
navigation controller: {  (самый главный контрол навигации) 
  view controller: {  
    tab bar controller: {  
      navigation controller: {  
        view controller (я тут)
      },  
      navigation controller: {  
        view controller  
      },  
      navigation controller: {  
        view controller  
      }  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Как получить доступ из контрола "я тут" к UINavigationController, который "самый главный"

Comment: может проще все переписать нормально :)

Comment: предполагая, что ваш нав контроллер является рутом окна, можно попробовать так `UINavigationController *controller = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;`

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko к сожалению, нет человека, который бы подталкивал к лучшей практике, а как бы Вы переписали мое чудовище? =) у меня есть контрол приветствия, контроллер с авторизацией и таббар контроллер, я хотел бы держать как можно меньше контроллеров в памяти и думал, что если авторизированный пользователь запускает приложение, то его кидает сразу же на таббар, а если он захотел выйти, то при нажатии, сделать так, чтобы в таббаре можно было сделать pop и первым элементом в верхнем контроле навигации появилось окно приветствия

Comment: помог комментарий мой про рут?

Comment: а касательно переписать, я бы сказал либо сделать таб бар рутом, а авторизицию проводить через модальный вью; либо показать приветствие и авторизицию на одном нав контроллере, а после авторизации заменить его на таб бар

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko извините, совсем забыл, что решил стучаться как Вы подсказали и в методе setViewControllers(viewControllers:, animated:) сетаю что нужно, оформите ответ, и отмечу его, как верный. Либо, можете подсказать, как следовало бы оформить авторизацию через модальное окно так, чтобы пользователь, при заходе в приложение первый раз, не видел этих нескольких анимаций, пустой таб бар -> авторизация, как нибдуь так, чтобы сразу была видна авторизация.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

предполагая, что ваш нав контроллер является рутом окна, можно попробовать так

```
UINavigationController *controller = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
```